# When I json_encode an array of URLs it replaces periods with underscores

Tags: php, json

What causes json_encode() to replace periods with underscores?  I can't have it doing this in my script as it then breaks my curl calls that use the URL array.

Comment: what does your string look like?

Comment: http://mail.google.com/mail/?hl=en&tab=wm

Comment: are you using `json_decode()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When PHP *receives* POST/GET variables (which I assume this is about, because `json_encode` wont't do it), [replaces dots in keys with an underscore](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php) (a `register_globals` legacy I think).

Either work around it, or manually parse either `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` for `GET`'s or `file_get_contents('php://input');` for `POST`.

Comment: Yep you hit it on the head.  I'm sending it via GET to PHP and the receiving script is getting bad data.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me:

```
>> json_encode(array('www.url.com','mail.google.com/mail/?hl=en&tab=wm'));
'["www.url.com","mail.google.com\\/mail\\/?hl=en&tab=wm"]'
```

It's not json_encode(). Something else is doing this.

Comment: Yep indeed it is something else causing the issue.